# How to get the uniform current date time throughout each loop in Airflow?

Tags: python, datetime, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Below is a format of the DAG used,
I am using for loop over input files in the DAG and rename the output files using the

```
CurrentDateTime = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

> #if currentDateTIme = 20210406010203

```
outputfile = ''
outputfile1 = ''
outputfile2 = ''
inputfiles = ['input1', 'input2']

API_CALL_TASK1 = {
source : inputfile1
filename : outputfile1 #20210406010513
}

API_CALL_TASK2 = {
source : inputfile2
filename : outputfile2 
}

for file in inputfiles:
    if file == 'input1'
        outputfile1 = f'inputFileName_{CurrentDateTime}' #20210406010303
        outputfile = f'inputFileName_{CurrentDateTime}' #20210406010303
    if file == 'input2'
        outputfile2 = f'inputFileName_{CurrentDateTime}' 
        outputfile = f'inputFileName_{CurrentDateTime}'        
    MOVE_OUTPUT_TO_BUCKET_TASK = (
                                 filename = f{outputfile} #20210406010423
                                 )
```

`MOVE_OUTPUT_TO_BUCKET_TASK >> API_CALL_TASK1 >> API_CALL_TASK1`

Here in the tasks - `API_CALL_TASK1`, `API_CALL_TASK2` and to the `MOVE_OUTPUT_TO_BUCKET_TASK` the datetime in the filename is different as there is difference in time when each task is triggered.

How to get the uniform datetime for each file?

I want to pass the same filename from the loop to the `MOVE_OUTPUT_TO_BUCKET_TASK` and `API_CALL_TASK1` or `API_CALL_TASK2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to pass the same datetime in the format `YYYYMMDD` for both outputs in the loop.

Airflow provides us a set of ***Default Variables***, which can be used across all templates. So you can use it to pass a constant value throughout your template. In your case, I see that you want the execution date to be the suffix of your output. Thus, you should use `ds_nodash`, as per [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#id1), it retrieves `the execution date as YYYYMMDD`.

In case you are using a Python operator with **kwargs, you can access it as `kwargs['ds_nodash']`.

Comment: can I get two seperate {{ts_nodash}} in airflow dag? because of the same datetime obtained by {{ts_nodash}} my output is getting overwritten. is there a way to increment {{ts_nodash}} with 1-2 secs like we can do - airflow.macros.ds_add(ds, days) ds_add('2015-01-01', 5) for {{ ds }} @Alexandre Moraes

Comment: @RavaliR, according to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html), there is no such a function for `td_nodash`. However, you could add another suffix to your output to differentiate it. As I mentioned before, Airflow's variables will be constant throughout the template. Also, if you found the information above useful, please accept and upvote the answer. I would appreciate that.